# Creating one to many relationship with pivot table of many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Users table structure: users

id, name, username, password, created_at, updated_at

Article table structure: article

id, title, content, created_at, updated_at

Relationship table: article_user

id, article_id, user_id, is_active, created_at, updated_at

Tags

id, name, user_id, created_at, updated_at

Relation of pivot table article_user with tags. table: article_user_tag

tag_id, article_user_id

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','username','password'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article')->withPivot('is_active')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','content'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('is_active')->withTimestamps();;
    }

        public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }       
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','content'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I want to connect these table so I can access like this or similar format

```
$user->articles()->first()->tags;
```

and should be able to create/update as well, smth like this

```
$user->articles()->first()->create(['title'=>'testing','content'=>'content'])->attach(['tag_id_1','tag_id_2','tag_id_3']);
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','username','password'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleUser')->with('article');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }
}

class ArticleUser extends Model
{
    public funciton article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','content'];
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','content'];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ArticleUser')->with('article');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```